# Broken link to blog post for Annual Salary Calculator

Tags: bug, status-completed, broken-link, salary-calculator

On [my results page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary?ff=1&dr=FullStackDeveloper&l=Mount+Pleasant%2C+MI+48858%2C+United+States&ed=1&ex=12&tl=javascript&tl=php&tl=ruby&tl=sql), the following markup contains a broken link

> Salary is a pre-tax value based on the 2017 Developer Survey results. [Learn more](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/19/how-much-do-developers-earn-find-out-with-the-stack-overflow-salary-calculator) about our methodology.

The (broken) link points to: https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/19/how-much-do-developers-earn-find-out-with-the-stack-overflow-salary-calculator/
It appears the link should point to: https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/19/much-developers-earn-find-stack-overflow-salary-calculator/

Comment: fixing... this was a bad merge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting it! I did a... "fun" merge and missed this line.

It's now fixed.

Comment: "Fun" merges so often are just the opposite. Thanks!